# How to add "default recipients" ($DEFAULT_RECIPIENTS) to recipientProviders in Jenkins EmailExt?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I am using Jenkins and Emailext plugin for emailing. Here is a test pipeline, which works fine:

```yaml
pipeline
{
  agent any

  stages
  {
    stage ('Start')
    {
      steps
      {
        echo 'Hello'
        // error('Abort to test failure.')
      }
    }
  }

  post
  {
    success
    {
      emailext (
          subject: '$DEFAULT_SUBJECT',
          body: '$DEFAULT_CONTENT',
          recipientProviders: [ requestor(), ? ]
        )
    }

    failure
    {
      emailext (
          subject: '$DEFAULT_SUBJECT',
          body: '$DEFAULT_CONTENT',
          recipientProviders: [developers(), requestor(), culprits()]
        )
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to send `success` emails to `requestor` and to "default recipients" which I specified under `Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Extended E-mail Notification`.

How do I add "default recipients" (`$DEFAULT_RECIPIENTS`) to `recipientProviders`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this:

```yaml
success
    {
      emailext (
          subject: '$DEFAULT_SUBJECT',
          body: '$DEFAULT_CONTENT',
          to: '$DEFAULT_RECIPIENTS',
          recipientProviders: [ requestor() ]
        )
    }
```

> `recipientProviders` parameter is used to add additional recipients.

This will send the email to both `recipientProviders` and `DEFAULT_RECIPIENTS` whenever job is success.

Comment: A much surprising solution... :-)

Comment: how do you get this DEFAULT_RECIPIENT value for a different, non-pipeline job? its a hack, but want to use it to setup email groups for sets of jobs, so i dont have to keep repeating it in each job.

Comment: You can use shared libraries for your use case @mike01010